# Where is the ODBC driver in DatabaseLink for Microsoft Access?

Tags: databaselink, version-13

I have an access database file which 925MB. When trying to establish connection with it using:

```
connection=OpenSQLConnection[
    JDBC[
        "Microsoft Access(UCanAccess)",
        file
    ]
]
```

It takes very long for smaller databases but for this one it keeps running out of java heap size. Currently, the maximum java heap size is set as follows:

```
ReinstallJava[JVMArguments->"-Xmx4096m"]
```

What I am not understanding is why does it need so much RAM just to establish the connection? Is it importing the entire database into memory?

Is there a better driver than the `"Microsoft Access(UCanAccess)"` for accessing the Microsoft Access database? I saw in some of the older questions that when running `JDBCDriverNames[]` there used to be an option `"Microsoft Access(ODBC)"` but now only `"Microsoft Access(UCanAccess)"` can be seen. Is there a way to use the ODBC driver which might be better than the UCanAccess driver? I am using Wolfram Desktop 13.0.